# Calling non-abstract method from subclass

Tags: java, abstract

Suggested to pass a File class object to `playClip()` that references the animal sound file and catches any exceptions outputting "Meow" if any exceptions were caught. When I run Main function I hear the cat sound in the speakers.

Have I passed the File object reference to `playClip()` the right way?

```
public void makeSound() {
  try {
    playClip(new File("Cat.wav"));
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Meow");
  }
}
```

With the following main function

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cat sound = new Cat();
    sound.makeSound();
  }
}
```

Comment: If this isn't Java, please [edit] your question to add the right language tag.

Comment: What do you mean by "call the actual method"? You didn't provide code that tries to call the method.

Comment: That is what my question is. I have tried using super.playClip() with errors.

Comment: What errors? Provide a message directly from your compilers with pointers to lines causing the errors.

Comment: If the method in the abstract class is already implemented, then just call it like you would any method.

Comment: you want to call the abstract makeSound(); method in abstract class Sound? if yes that's impossible. you need to call it from a class that has implemented it

Comment: This is java. I am trying to make "makeSound" call the playClip() method which is constained in the abstract class.

Comment: then what's the problem with calling playClip from inside of makeSound inside the Cat class?

Comment: WJS, yes in my subclass that I have created I am implementing "makeSound()". And trying to call playClip(). I used  playClip(File clipFile);     to call the method but java cannot resolve the symbol "clipFile".    I am simply trying to call the method guess just like calling any other method.

Comment: It sounds like you called it right, by passing in a File. Is everything working, is this done?

Answer (score 0):

In your abstract class, create the method playClip:

```
public abstract class Sound {

    abstract public void makeSound();

    public void playClip(File clipFile) {  
        // code plays a file and has some exception handling
    }
}


    public class Cat extends Sound {

        public Cat() {

        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void makeSound() {
        playClip(new File("/sound_file"));
    }
}
```

Of course, playClip() could also be abstract. It depends what you want.

Comment: I now have this: